# How to read value from property inside JToken by either using the method TryGetPropertyValue or JSON path?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

Given a `JToken` called *distance* with the following content

```
{ "232": { "travelDistance": 25.0 } }
```

I would like to read the field *travelDistance* from it. First I tried this

```
distance.TryGetPropertyValue("travelDistance", float.MaxValue)
```

but this returns the fallback value `float.MaxValue`. Then I tried to use a JSON path

```
distance.SelectToken("$.travelDistance")
```

but this returns `null`. These are my debugging results

[image]

How can I read the value of the property *travelDistance*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `JObject` you can read the field values

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var result = Convert.ToDecimal(jObj["232"]["travelDistance"]);
```

OR

```
var result1 = Convert.ToDecimal(jObj.SelectToken("232.travelDistance"));
```

OR

```
var result2 = Convert.ToDecimal(jObj.SelectToken("*.travelDistance"));
```

OR

```
var result3 = jObj.SelectTokens("*.travelDistance")
                  .Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x))?
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```